# Finding best reciprocal matches

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr, match

This is a problem of finding best reciprocal matches between two sets of strings that were mapped one against the other.

What I have are the two `data.frame`'s that hold the results of mapping the first set against the other (`df1` below) and the of other mapping direction (`df2` below).

The mapping obtains a `score`. In addition, every string has a `parent`, and several different strings have the same `parent`.

Here are simulated data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

#generate the first string set mapping data.frame
df1 <- data.frame(query = paste("a",unlist(sapply(1:5,function(i) rep(i,ceiling(runif(1,1,3))))),sep="."),stringsAsFactors = F)

#add hits and scores
df1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df1$query),function(q) {
  dplyr::filter(df1,query == q) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(hit = paste("b",sample(5,nrow(.),replace = F),sep="."),score = runif(nrow(.),0,100))

})) 

#add parents
df1 <- left_join(df1,data.frame(query=unique(df1$query),parent = paste("p.a",sample(3,5,replace=T),sep="."),stringsAsFactors = F),by=c("query"="query"))

#generate the second string set mapping data.frame
df2 <- data.frame(query = paste("b",unlist(sapply(1:5,function(i) rep(i,ceiling(runif(1,1,3))))),sep="."),stringsAsFactors = F)

#add hits and scores
df2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df2$query),function(q) {
  dplyr::filter(df2,query == q) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(hit = paste("a",sample(5,nrow(.),replace = F),sep="."),
                  score = runif(nrow(.),0,100))

})) 

#add parents
df2 <- left_join(df2,data.frame(query=unique(df2$query),parent = paste("p.b",sample(3,5,replace=T),sep="."),stringsAsFactors = F),by=c("query"="query"))
```

What I want is to have an efficient function that returns the following:

for each string in the first set (`unique(df1$query)`), if the string it maps to with the highest `score` maps back to it with its highest `score` (reciprocal best hit) return that hit's id, the mapping `score`, and the hit's `parent` id, otherwise return `NA` for the hit's id and `score`. As for the parent, return the hit's `parent` id if the `parent`s are best reciprocal matches, otherwise return `NA`.

The resulting `data.frame` should have these columns:
`set.a.id`, `set.a.parent.id`, `set.b.match`, `set.b.match.score`, `set.b.parent.id`.

For `df1` and df2, ordered by `query` and `score`:

```
df1[order(df1$query,-df1$score),]
   query hit    score parent
1    a.1 b.4 84.72860  p.a.1
2    a.1 b.1 57.64333  p.a.1
3    a.1 b.2 56.02473  p.a.1
5    a.2 b.3 82.18000  p.a.2
4    a.2 b.4 72.56507  p.a.2
6    a.2 b.1 59.24316  p.a.2
7    a.3 b.3 71.47014  p.a.3
8    a.3 b.4 22.60246  p.a.3
10   a.4 b.2 35.13778  p.a.2
11   a.4 b.1 26.89667  p.a.2
9    a.4 b.4 20.33758  p.a.2
12   a.5 b.2 26.85910  p.a.2
13   a.5 b.4 26.77832  p.a.2



df2[order(df2$query,-df2$score),]
   query hit    score parent
1    b.1 a.2 90.76623  p.b.2
2    b.1 a.5 24.57950  p.b.2
3    b.2 a.5 39.58975  p.b.1
4    b.2 a.1 39.11946  p.b.1
6    b.3 a.5 35.94917  p.b.1
5    b.3 a.4 11.57524  p.b.1
8    b.4 a.5 80.93301  p.b.2
7    b.4 a.4 57.07636  p.b.2
9    b.4 a.3 10.13098  p.b.2
11   b.5 a.5 49.70569  p.b.1
10   b.5 a.2 12.88346  p.b.1
```

This is the resulting `data.frame`:

```
res.df <- data.frame(set.a.id = unique(df1$query),set.a.parent.id = unique(df1$parent),
                     set.b.match = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"b.2"),set.b.match.score = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,26.85910),
                     set.b.parent.id = c(NA,"p.b.1",NA,"p.b.1","p.b.1"))
```

Comment: What are you mapping the strings to? What is the id? There are no id columns. What makes a parent a reciprocal best match? There are no matching parents between the two sets. Please edit your question to reflect the data that is actually inside your data.frames.